# Replace all particular values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Having a data frame, how do I go about replacing all particular values along all rows and columns. Say for example I want to replace all empty records with `NA`'s (without typing the positions):

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c("", "xyz", "jkl"), B=c(12, "", 100)))

    A   B
1      12
2  xyz    
3  jkl 100
```

Expected result:

```
    A   B
1  NA   12
2  xyz  NA  
3  jkl  100
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Like this:

```
> df[df==""]<-NA
> df
     A    B
1 <NA>   12
2  xyz <NA>
3  jkl  100
```

Comment: is there a way to do this efficiently for more than 1 value!?

Comment: This doesn't work for factors, `df[df=="xyz"]<-"abc"` will error with "invalid factor level." Is there a more general solution?

Comment: not working for me. I tried this:
 dfSmallDiscreteCustomSalary[dfSmallDiscreteCustomSalary$salary=="<=50K"] <- "49K".
Still for unique(dfSmallDiscreteCustomSalary$salary) i get:
[1]  >50K   <=50K

Comment: glallen ... if you're trying to modify a factor column with a new value that already a factor, there are probably more clever ways that what I'm about to suggest, but you could df$factorcolumn <- as.character(df$factorcolumn), then make your modification, and finish off by turning it back into a factor again... df$factorcolumn <- as.factor(df$factorcolumn); it'll be complete with your new level and desired value.

Comment: Found it out: df.na.replace(df.columns, Map("" -> "NA")).show. Interestingly I am not able to replace with null as value. I am getting : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value type java.lang.String (null).
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameNaFunctions$$convertToDouble(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:434)

Answer (score 39):

Since PikkuKatja and glallen asked for a more general solution and I cannot comment yet, I'll write an answer. You can combine statements as in:

```
> df[df=="" | df==12] <- NA
> df
     A    B
1  <NA> <NA>
2  xyz  <NA>
3  jkl  100
```

For factors, zxzak's code already yields factors:

```
> df <- data.frame(list(A=c("","xyz","jkl"), B=c(12,"",100)))
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "","jkl","xyz": 1 3 2
 $ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "","100","12": 3 1 2
```

If in trouble, I'd suggest to temporarily drop the factors.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

Answer (score 31):

Here are a couple `dplyr` options:

```
library(dplyr)

# all columns:
df %>% 
  mutate_all(~na_if(., ''))

# specific column types:
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, ~na_if(., ''))

# specific columns:  
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(A, B), ~na_if(., ''))

# or:
df %>% 
  mutate(A = replace(A, A == '', NA))

# replace can be used if you want something other than NA:
df %>% 
  mutate(A = as.character(A)) %>% 
  mutate(A = replace(A, A == '', 'used to be empty'))
```

Comment: How would you go about using the all columns solution to replace several strings by NAs in the whole dataset?

Comment: These options are still perfectly valid, just note that the the "mutate_at" and "mutate_all" functions have been superseded with the "across()." They're still supported, but R recommends "across()" instead.

More details here:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

Answer (score 5):

We can use data.table to get it quickly.
First create df without factors,

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c("","xyz","jkl"), B=c(12,"",100)), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Now you can use

```
setDT(df)
for (jj in 1:ncol(df)) set(df, i = which(df[[jj]]==""), j = jj, v = NA)
```

and you can convert it back to a data.frame

```
setDF(df)
```

If you only want to use data.frame and keep factors it's more difficult, you need to work with

```
levels(df$value)[levels(df$value)==""] <- NA
```

where value is the name of every column. You need to insert it in a loop.

Comment: Why would you use an external library for this use case? Why a loop if this can be solved with one line? How does your answer add value beyond the answers already present? I don't intend to be harsh, I think I am missing something, hence the questions.

Comment: It's much faster for large datasets. It adds an alternative so that the user can choose the best for him.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace multiple values in a data frame, looping through all columns might help.

Say you want to replace `""` and `100`:

```
na_codes <- c(100, "")
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    df[[i]][df[[i]] %in% na_codes] <- NA
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a solution is missing for [multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503266/replace-all-particular-values-in-a-data-frame#comment46216842_19503330) to be replaced and for [factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503266/replace-all-particular-values-in-a-data-frame#comment52563234_19503330), so I will add one.

Consider a data frame `dat` with various classes.

```
dat
#    character integer       Date factor               POSIX
# 1                  4 2022-07-10      B 2022-07-10 20:08:10
# 2                  1 2022-07-11    FOO 2022-07-10 21:08:10
# 3                 -2 2022-07-12        2022-07-10 22:08:10
# 4                  2 2022-07-13      B 2022-07-10 23:08:10
# 5          a       3 2022-07-14        2022-07-11 00:08:10
# 6          c       1 2022-07-15        2022-07-11 01:08:10
# 7          a      -1 2022-07-16    FOO 2022-07-11 02:08:10
# 8          a      -1 2022-07-17      A 2022-07-11 03:08:10
# 9                  4 2022-07-18    FOO 2022-07-11 04:08:10
# 10         c       0 2022-07-19    FOO 2022-07-11 05:08:10
# 11         b      -2 2022-07-20      B 2022-07-11 06:08:10
# 12         c      -2 2022-07-21      A 2022-07-11 07:08:10
```

We may put everything we want to convert to NA on a list `to_na`,

```
To_NA <- list('', -1, -2, 'c', 'FOO', as.Date('2022-07-17'), as.POSIXct('2022-07-11 00:08:10'))
```

and use it in a small function `make_na` based on `replace`. `if` the respective variable `is.factor` we may want to `droplevels` of values that have just been deleted.

```
make_na <- \(x, z) {x <- replace(x, x %in% z, NA); if (is.factor(x)) droplevels(x) else x}
```

We can apply it on a vector,

```
make_na(dat$character, To_NA)
# [1] NA  NA  NA  NA  "a" NA  "a" "a" NA  NA  "b" NA
```

or loop over the columns using `lapply`.

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, make_na, To_NA)
```

#### Gives

```
dat
#    character integer       Date factor               POSIX
# 1       <NA>       4 2022-07-10      B 2022-07-10 20:08:10
# 2       <NA>       1 2022-07-11   <NA> 2022-07-10 21:08:10
# 3       <NA>      NA 2022-07-12   <NA> 2022-07-10 22:08:10
# 4       <NA>       2 2022-07-13      B 2022-07-10 23:08:10
# 5          a       3 2022-07-14   <NA>                <NA>
# 6       <NA>       1 2022-07-15   <NA> 2022-07-11 01:08:10
# 7          a      NA 2022-07-16   <NA> 2022-07-11 02:08:10
# 8          a      NA       <NA>      A 2022-07-11 03:08:10
# 9       <NA>       4 2022-07-18   <NA> 2022-07-11 04:08:10
# 10      <NA>       0 2022-07-19   <NA> 2022-07-11 05:08:10
# 11         b      NA 2022-07-20      B 2022-07-11 06:08:10
# 12      <NA>      NA 2022-07-21      A 2022-07-11 07:08:10
```

Where:

```
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 12 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ character: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ integer  : int  4 1 NA 2 3 1 NA NA 4 0 ...
#  $ Date     : Date, format: "2022-07-10" "2022-07-11" "2022-07-12" ...
#  $ factor   : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 2 NA NA 2 NA NA NA 1 NA NA ...
#  $ POSIX    : POSIXct, format: "2022-07-10 20:08:10" "2022-07-10 21:08:10" "2022-07-10 22:08:10" ...
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(character = c("", "", "", "", "a", "c", "a", "a", 
"", "c", "b", "c"), integer = c(4L, 1L, -2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, -1L, 
-1L, 4L, 0L, -2L, -2L), Date = structure(c(19183, 19184, 19185, 
19186, 19187, 19188, 19189, 19190, 19191, 19192, 19193, 19194
), class = "Date"), factor = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L), levels = c("", "A", "B", "FOO"), class = "factor"), 
    POSIX = structure(c(1657476490L, 1657480090L, 1657483690L, 
    1657487290L, 1657490890L, 1657494490L, 1657498090L, 1657501690L, 
    1657505290L, 1657508890L, 1657512490L, 1657516090L), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using `sapply`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
df <- data.frame(list(A=c("", "xyz", "jkl"), B=c(12, "", 100)))
df[sapply(df, \(x) x == "")] <- NA
df
#>      A    B
#> 1 <NA>   12
#> 2  xyz <NA>
#> 3  jkl  100
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Please note**: with R 4.1.0 and later you could use `\(x)` instead of `function(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `replace_with_na_all()` from the `naniar` package, which allows you to replace all the values meeting a condition in the entire dataframe.

```
library(naniar)
library(dplyr)
    
df %>% 
  replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x == "")
```

**Output**

```
  A     B    
  <chr> <chr>
1 NA    12   
2 xyz   NA   
3 jkl   100
```

The upside to this method is that if you also had some cells that also had spaces included, then we could provide both in the conditions argument. Although it would be better to first just trim the whitespace, then use the function above (i.e., adding `mutate(across(everything(), ~ trimws(.x)))` to the pipe).

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c("", "xyz", "  "), B=c(12, "   ", 100)))

df %>%
  replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% c("", "  ", "   "))

#  A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 NA    12   
#2 xyz   NA   
#3 NA    100
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s also possible to use the gsub function in combination with lapply.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) (gsub("", NA, x)))
```