# Regression Analysis in R

Tags: r

How to deal with a data which * in some cells before doing a regression analysis in R. Let sata i have two columns air weight and water weight with 
1000 rows , in certain rows it has this "*", how to deal with this "*"
before doing a correlation or regression in two columns

Answer (score 0):

If the data's in a dataframe, then `df[df == ""] <- NA` should work. This'll replace all empty cells with `NA` values.

If you have a specific character or string you want to replace just put it between the quotes:`df[df == "whatever"] <- NA`.

If you want to replace the values with something that's not `NA` put that between the quote marks: `df[df == ""] <- whatever`.

[Here's a link to a similar question, with a similar answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503266/r-replace-all-particular-values-in-a-data-frame) This answer probably should've just been a comment, but I can't make comments yet. The powers that be can just turn this into one, or do whatever they see fit with it.

Answer (score 0):

IF You have Excel file save it as .csv then open R and write command 
like:

```
data = read.csv(D:\"data.csv"header=TRUE)
```