# How to replace value in the dataframe

Tags: r

```
Data_Frame <- data.frame (
  Training = c("Strength", "Stamina", "Other"),
  Pulse = c(100, 150, 120),
  Duration = c(60, 30, 45)
)
```

I need to change value if the training is equal to stamina then the value of pulse would be 200

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might find answers in SO, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503266/replace-all-particular-values-in-a-data-frame).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `replace`.

```
Data_Frame <- transform(Data_Frame, Pulse=replace(Pulse, Training == 'Stamina', 200))
Data_Frame
#   Training Pulse Duration
# 1 Strength   100       60
# 2  Stamina   200       30
# 3    Other   120       45
```